# Using spark on AWS EMR; The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. but boto3 calls work just fine

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am trying to read a file in SPARK on EMR, that I have provided TEMPORARY credentials for in a different system (Illumina ICA).

When trying to read the file using spark.read.csv, using the S3 URI, it gives me the error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.csv.
: java.io.IOException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId;
```

But when I try the same credentials using a BOTO3 call, it works just fine, so the credentials (in the environment) are just fine.

Here's my test code (from a notebook)

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv('s3://stratus-gds-use1/241dd164-decb-48f6-eba1-08d881d902b2/dummy.vcf.gz', sep='\t')

#... Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.csv. ##: java.io.IOException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId;

access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
region=os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']
session_token=os.environ['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN']
bucket_name='stratus-gds-use1'
key_prefix='241dd164-decb-48f6-eba1-08d881d902b2/dummy.vcf.gz'

import boto3
s3_session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=access_key_id, 
                                   aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key,
                                   aws_session_token=session_token,
                                   region_name = region)
s3_client = s3_session.client('s3')

%ls -l dummy.vcf.gz
#-=> ls: cannot access dummy.vcf.gz: No such file or directory

r = s3_client.download_file(Filename='dummy.vcf.gz',
                          Bucket=bucket_name,
                          Key=key_prefix)


%ls -l dummy.vcf.gz
#-=> -rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 2535 Apr  6 18:45 dummy.vcf.gz
```

Any ideas why spark on AWS EMR cannot access the file with the provided S3 URI?

I have tested other S3 URIs like that and they work fine, so the java classes work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out the solutions. I needed to provide the temporary AWS credentials in the Spark configuration and provide the special class
`org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider` as well as the session_token..

So this is the procedure to ensure spark can read an S3 bucket with temporary credentials.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
conf = (
    pyspark.SparkConf()
        .set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider','org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider')
        .set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', access_key_id)
        .set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', secret_access_key)
        .set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.session.token', session_token)
)
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv(f's3a://{BUCKET}/{KEY_PREFIX}', sep='\t')
```